# Jumping mechanic in Scratch using mix of normally available and hidden/hacked blocks

Tags: scratch

So I have been working on different projects in Scratch, and I decided to make a jumping mechanic<sup>[project here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/955140356/)</sup> using both blocks that are normally accessible and hacked/hidden blocks.

Now here is how I am defining a jumping mechanic in a game for this project:

1. There must be some defined area where the player can land. (it doesn't fall through everything)
2. The player must come back down after the jump button is released.
3. Max. jump height doesn't matter in this case (as long as the player doesn't go out of bounds)

---

However I want to know: Can I use less blocks in my code while still satisfying all 3 of my requirements? (Removing the hacked blocks is fine only if it's replaced with a more optimized method)

Here is my code with only 24 blocks used<sup>[note 1][note 2]</sup>:

```
[scratchblocks]
go to x: (0) y: (0)
forever
while <<not <touching color [#ff0000] ?>>>
set [a v] to [0]
go to x: ((x position)) y: (((y position)) - (2))
end
while <<touching color [#ff0000] ?>>
set [a v] to [1]
while <<(a) = [1]>>
while <<key [. v] pressed?>>
go to x: ((x position)) y: (((y position)) + (4))
end
set [a v] to [0]
end
end
if on edge, bounce
end
[/scratchblocks]
```

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCgJp.png)

[image]

List of hacked blocks used:

```
Hacked/hidden block |Notes
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
while               |                                                                       |
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
<[] = []>           |Left side only allows variables                                        |
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
<[] + []>           |See above                                                              |
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
<[] - []>           |See above                                                              |
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
<key [. v] pressed?>|Normally you can only activate this block if pressing space, a-z or 0-9|
```

---

<sup>[note 1]</sup>The `when green flag clicked` block or any other block needed to start the project isn't needed as you can just click the code to run it.
<sup>[note 2]</sup>I actually counted 25 blocks, but maybe Scratch isn't counting the `<key [. v] pressed?>` block.